# Jackson Change JsonIgnore Dynamically

Tags: java, json, deserialization, jackson

I have a class and there are variables inside it as well. Sometimes I want to ignore some fields and sometimes not when deserializing (maybe at serializing too). How can I do it at Jackson?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

For serialization, "[filtering properties](http://www.cowtowncoder.com/blog/archives/2011/02/entry_443.html)" blog entry should help. Deserialization side has less support, since it is more common to want to filter out stuff that is written.

One possible approach is to sub-class `JacksonAnnotationIntrospector`, override method(s) that introspect ignorability of methods (and/or fields) to use whatever logic you want.

It might also help if you gave an example of practical application, i.e what and why you are trying to prevent from being deserialized.

Comment: Here is an explanation: http://www.jroller.com/RickHigh/entry/filtering_json_feeds_from_spring I don't use Roo and aspectj code give error at my Intellij IDEA8(thisJoinPoint and proceed methods can not recognized). It would be great if I could implement it as annotation as like described.

Comment: I have a Spring 3 REST application. I have a bean at my server side and I list them at client. However it has many fields and I dın't list every field of my bean at table. However at another page I list all the fields of my bean at another table. So my purpose is that I don't want to send all information to client side for efficiency.

Comment: Ok: but just to be clear -- when sending things, you are generally talking about serialization; deserialization is the reverse (reading JSON into objects). So perhaps you are looking for serialization feature instead? If so, link I mentioned would be very useful?

Comment: serialization is so important for me, you are right. I read that link and I will try to implement it, thanks for your help.

Comment: The link is superb! I find Fully dynamic filtering: `@JsonFilter` extrmemely well suited to my use case where I want more control in terms of fetching (serializing) but not beyond a certain level as it ends up getting recursively fetched. ORMs tend to be like that.

Answer (score 4):

You might want to use JsonViews  ( took it originally from http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonJsonViews - broken now - web archive link: https://web.archive.org/web/20170831135842/http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonJsonViews )

### Quoting it:

First, defining views means declaring classes; you can reuse existing ones, or just create bogus classes -- they are just view identifiers with relationship information (child inherits view membership from parents):

```
 // View definitions:
  class Views {
            static class Public { }
            static class ExtendedPublic extends PublicView { }
            static class Internal extends ExtendedPublicView { }
  }

  public class Bean {
            // Name is public
            @JsonView(Views.Public.class) String name;
            // Address semi-public
            @JsonView(Views.ExtendPublic.class) Address address;
            // SSN only for internal usage
            @JsonView(Views.Internal.class) SocialSecNumber ssn;
  }
```

With such view definitions, serialization would be done like so:

```
 // short-cut:
  objectMapper.writeValueUsingView(out, beanInstance, ViewsPublic.class);

  // or fully exploded:
  objectMapper.getSerializationConfig().setSerializationView(Views.Public.class);
  // (note: can also pre-construct config object with 'mapper.copySerializationConfig'; reuse)
  objectMapper.writeValue(out, beanInstance); // will use active view set via Config

  // or, starting with 1.5, more convenient (ObjectWriter is reusable too)
  objectMapper.viewWriter(ViewsPublic.class).writeValue(out, beanInstance);
and result would only contain 'name', not 'address' or 'ssn'.
```

Answer (score 0):

You should probably look at the [modules feature](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonFeatureModules) of recent Jackson versions.

One possible mechanism would be to use a [BeanDeserializerModifier](http://jackson.codehaus.org/1.9.0/javadoc/org/codehaus/jackson/map/deser/BeanDeserializerModifier.html).

I've been looking for a useful online tutorial or example, but nothing immediately appears. It might be possible to work something up if more is known of your context. Are you managing your `ObjectMapper`s manually, or using them in a JAX-RS setting, injected in Spring, or what?

Answer (score 0):

I searched the entire web (yes I did) to find the answer. then I wrote something on my own.

I'm working with Jackson ion deserialisation. I wrote a custom reader that ignores the fields dynamically.

You can do the same thing for json deserialisation.

Lets assume an entity like this.

```
User {
    id
    name
    address {
       city
    }
}
```

Create a tree structure to represent field selection.

```
public class IonField {

    private final String name;
    private final IonField parent;
    private final Set<IonField> fields = new HashSet<>();

    // add constructs and stuff
}
```

Custom Ion Reader extending from amazon ion-java https://github.com/amzn/ion-java

```
public class IonReaderBinaryUserXSelective extends IonReaderBinaryUserX {

    private IonField _current;
    private int hierarchy = 0;

    public IonReaderBinaryUserXSelective(byte[] data, int offset, int length,
                                         IonSystem system, IonField _current) {
        super(system, system.getCatalog(), UnifiedInputStreamX.makeStream(data, offset, length));
        this._current = _current;
    }

    @Override
    public IonType next() {
        IonType type = super.next();

        if (type == null) {
            return null;
        }

        String file_name = getFieldName();

        if (file_name == null || SystemSymbols.SYMBOLS.equals(file_name)) {
            return type;
        }

        if (type == IonType.STRUCT || type == IonType.LIST) {
            IonField field = _current.getField(getFieldName());
            if (field != null) {
                this._current = field;
                return type;
            } else {
                super.stepIn();
                super.stepOut();
            }
            return next();
        } else {
            if (this._current.contains(file_name)) {
                return type;
            } else {
                return next();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void stepIn() {
        hierarchy = (hierarchy << 1);
        if (getFieldName() != null && !SystemSymbols.SYMBOLS.equals(getFieldName())) {
            hierarchy = hierarchy + 1;
        }
        super.stepIn();
    }

    @Override
    public void stepOut() {
        if ((hierarchy & 1) == 1) {
            this._current = this._current.getParent();
        }
        hierarchy = hierarchy >> 1;
        super.stepOut();
    }
```

Construct dynamic view. This Tree dynamically created and passed to the reader to deserialise.

Let's say we only need city inside the address.

```
IonField root = new IonField("user", null);

IonField address = new IonField("address", root);
IonField city = new IonField("city", address);
address.addChild(city);

root.addChild(id);


//now usual stuff.

IonFactory ionFactory = new IonFactory();
IonObjectMapper mapper = new IonObjectMapper(ionFactory);

File file = new File("file.bin"); // ion bytes

byte[] ionData =  Files.readAllBytes(file.toPath());

IonSystem ionSystem = IonSystemBuilder.standard().build();
IonReader ionReader = new IonReaderBinaryUserXSelective(ionData, 0, ionData.length, ionSystem, root);

User user = mapper.readValue(ionReader, User.class);
```

Comment: this could help understand. https://amzn.github.io/ion-docs/guides/cookbook.html#down-converting-to-json