# Jackson JSON Ignore Properties Dynamically

Tags: json, jackson

I have the following classes -

**Employee**

```
public class Employee {

    private String firstName ;
    private String lastName ;
    private String emailAddress ; 
    private String ssn ;
}
```

**Payroll**

```
public class Payroll {

    // different payroll related fields

    private Employee emp ;

}
```

**HR**

```
public class HR {

    // different HR related fields

    private Employee emp ;

}
```

Now when I serialize my Payroll class, I don't want to serialize my ssn field from Employee class.

Where as when I serialize my HR class, I don't want to serialize my emailAddress field from Employee class.

How I can dynamically exclude fields from serializing by using Jackson JSON API?

Answer (score 6):

> How I can dynamically exclude fields from serializing by using Jackson JSON API?

This seems like a prime candidate for applying [JacksonJsonViews](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonJsonViews).

```
public class Employee {

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    @JsonView(Views.Payroll.class) private String emailAddress; 
    @JsonView(Views.HR.class) private String ssn;
}

public class Payroll {
    // snip

    @JsonView(Views.Payroll.class)
    private Employee emp;
}

public class HR {
    // snip

    @JsonView(Views.HR.class)
    private Employee emp;
}
```

Comment: If there is yet an other class, say Department which has Employee as an object and when serialized want to serialize everything from Employee, how does that work ?

Comment: The linked documentation covers this. You could just disable view processing entirely in that case.

Comment: Is there a way to choose which views are used based on some value determined at runtime and have it change? If not, then this doesn't answer the "dynamically" part of the question.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this with the help of a JsonFilter.

1. Annotate the class you want to filter as thus:

```
@JsonFilter("employeeFilter")
public class Employee {

    private String firstName ;
    private String lastName ;
    private String emailAddress ; 
    private String ssn ;
}
```

2. Create a service called FilterBeanService(Or anything really)

```
@Service
public class FilterBeanService {

    // fields is an array of field names you wish not to sned in your response
    // beanFilterName is value you give when you annotage your bean class
    // dataSet is the data you want to filter
    public static MappingJacksonValue filterBean(String[] fields, String beanFilterName, Object dataSet ) {
        SimpleBeanPropertyFilter filter = SimpleBeanPropertyFilter.serializeAllExcept(fields);
        FilterProvider filterProvider = new SimpleFilterProvider().addFilter(beanFilterName, filter);
        MappingJacksonValue jacksonValue = new MappingJacksonValue(dataSet);
        jacksonValue.setFilters(filterProvider);
        return jacksonValue;
    }
}
```

3. In your controller, you can then filter fileds you do not want

```
@GetMapping("/whatever")
public ResponseEntity<MappingJacksonValue> getSomething(){
   List<Employee> employees = eventRepo.findAll();
   String[] fields = {"ssn"};
   MappingJacksonValue jacksonValue = FilterBeanService.filterBean(fields, "employeeFilter", employees);
   return jacksonValue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I answered below to dynamically deserialise with customer reader. Can do similar thing with writer to ignore when serialising.

[Jackson Change JsonIgnore Dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8179986/jackson-change-jsonignore-dynamically/68837998#68837998)