# Ignore fields from Java object dynamically while sending as JSON from Spring MVC

Tags: java, json, hibernate, spring-mvc

I have model class like this, for hibernate

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user", catalog = "userdb")
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class User implements java.io.Serializable {

    private Integer userId;
    private String userName;
    private String emailId;
    private String encryptedPwd;
    private String createdBy;
    private String updatedBy;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "UserId", unique = true, nullable = false)
    public Integer getUserId() {
        return this.userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(Integer userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    @Column(name = "UserName", length = 100)
    public String getUserName() {
        return this.userName;
    }

    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }

    @Column(name = "EmailId", nullable = false, length = 45)
    public String getEmailId() {
        return this.emailId;
    }

    public void setEmailId(String emailId) {
        this.emailId = emailId;
    }

    @Column(name = "EncryptedPwd", length = 100)
    public String getEncryptedPwd() {
        return this.encryptedPwd;
    }

    public void setEncryptedPwd(String encryptedPwd) {
        this.encryptedPwd = encryptedPwd;
    }

    public void setCreatedBy(String createdBy) {
        this.createdBy = createdBy;
    }

    @Column(name = "UpdatedBy", length = 100)
    public String getUpdatedBy() {
        return this.updatedBy;
    }

    public void setUpdatedBy(String updatedBy) {
        this.updatedBy = updatedBy;
    }
}
```

In Spring MVC controller, using DAO, I am able to get the object. and returning as JSON Object.

```
@Controller
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/getUser/{userId}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public User getUser(@PathVariable Integer userId) throws Exception {

        User user = userService.get(userId);
        user.setCreatedBy(null);
        user.setUpdatedBy(null);
        return user;
    }
}
```

View part is done using AngularJS, so it will get JSON like this

```
{
  "userId" :2,
  "userName" : "john",
  "emailId" : "john@gmail.com",
  "encryptedPwd" : "Co7Fwd1fXYk=",
  "createdBy" : null,
  "updatedBy" : null
}
```

If I don't want to set encrypted Password, I will set that field also as null.

But I don't want like this, I dont want to send all fields to client side. If I dont want password, updatedby, createdby fields to send, My result JSON should be like

```
{
  "userId" :2,
  "userName" : "john",
  "emailId" : "john@gmail.com"
}
```

The list of fields which I don't want to send to client coming from other database table. So it will change based on the user who is logged in.  How can I do that?

I hope You got my question.

Comment: What would you say about this answer? http://stackoverflow.com/a/30559076/3488143

Comment: this information may be helpful
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12505141/only-using-jsonignore-during-serialization-but-not-deserialization/36965995#36965995

Comment: I answered here
[Easy way to filter fields dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69102018/14965133)

Comment: To dynamically  ignore the field in json response, before you send back your response, try setting that field to null i.e ```entityClass.setFieldToIgnore(null)```. The spring-mvc is by default set to ignore null values when deserializing, or you can configure it manually

Answer (score 189):

Add the `@JsonIgnoreProperties("fieldname")` annotation  to your POJO.

Or you can use `@JsonIgnore` before the name of the field you want to ignore while deserializing JSON. Example:

```
@JsonIgnore
@JsonProperty(value = "user_password")
public String getUserPassword() {
    return userPassword;
}
```

[GitHub example](https://gist.github.com/thurloat/2510887)

Comment: Can I do it dynamically? Not in POJO? Can I do it in my Controller class?

Comment: @iProgrammer : here is a similar as you want :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8179986/jackson-change-jsonignore-dynamically

Comment: @iProgrammer : very impressive answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13764280/how-do-i-exclude-fields-with-jackson-not-using-annotations

Comment: remark:`@JsonIgnore` is `com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore` not `org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonIgnore`.

Comment: That ignores both while reading from request and while sending response. I want to ignore only while sending response because i need that property from the request object. Any ideas?

Comment: Hello @zulkarnainshah: you can use json serializer then.

Comment: @user3145373ツ. I think I need to set the JSONIgnore on the getter method of that field and remove it from the field itself.

Comment: @zulkarnainshah: refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12505141/only-using-jsonignore-during-serialization-but-not-deserialization for more details

Comment: @user3145373ツ Ya the JSONIgnore needs to be only on top of the getter method. Thanks !

Comment: I guess `JsonFilter` annotation is what you need.

Comment: @user3145373ツ this does not work for inner class. what should be done to make it work for attributes/fields in the inner class ?

Comment: @user641887 you need to use same annotation in inner class. If you do not want to whole inner class then you need to add annotation in parent one.

Comment: @user3145373ツ i want few fields of the inner class but not all. adding annotation on the fields of the inner class which i dont need does not work.

Comment: @user641887 Annotation work at any place, parent-child it does not matter.

Comment: It is not the answer for THAT question. Why the @iCode accepted it I couldn't understand.

Comment: @Olkunmustafa: Can you please explain what's wrong in this and what actually -iCode wants? If something is wrong then happy to correct it.

Comment: @user3145373ツ Because -iCode is asking to change response dynamically not in POJO. Already he commented about it but the answer accepted I couldn't understand. Correct answer should be this one => https://stackoverflow.com/a/51990626/2834196

Comment: Another solution is to use a Data Transfer Object (DTO) which allows to only send fields that your client needs. This object will only have `userId`, `userName` and `emailId` as attributes.

Comment: But to not to add this attribute in serialization and de-serialization we and define '@JsonIgnore' at data-member level:

@JsonIgnore
private String userPassword;

Answer (score 54):

> Can I do it dynamically?

Create view class:

```
public class View {
    static class Public { }
    static class ExtendedPublic extends Public { }
    static class Internal extends ExtendedPublic { }
}
```

Annotate you model

```
@Document
public class User {

    @Id
    @JsonView(View.Public.class)
    private String id;

    @JsonView(View.Internal.class)
    private String email;

    @JsonView(View.Public.class)
    private String name;

    @JsonView(View.Public.class)
    private Instant createdAt = Instant.now();
    // getters/setters
}
```

Specify the view class in your controller

```
@RequestMapping("/user/{email}")
public class UserController {

    private final UserRepository userRepository;

    @Autowired
    UserController(UserRepository userRepository) {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @JsonView(View.Internal.class)
    public @ResponseBody Optional<User> get(@PathVariable String email) {
        return userRepository.findByEmail(email);
    }

}
```

Data example:

```
{"id":"5aa2496df863482dc4da2067","name":"test","createdAt":"2018-03-10T09:35:31.050353800Z"}
```

UPD: keep in mind that it's not best practice to use entity in response. Better use different DTO for each case and fill them using `modelmapper`

Comment: This is a fantastic and minimalistic answer! I wanted to return as a JSON just only few fields from a @Configuration annotated component and skipping all the internal fields that are automatically included. Thanks a lot!

Comment: This should be the accepted solution. Really helped. Thanks @Hett

Comment: Don't forget to add spring.jackson.mapper.default-view-inclusion=true to cascade to child objects, see here https://stackoverflow.com/a/57928379/18209257

Answer (score 41):

I know I'm a bit late to the party, but I actually ran into this as well a few months back. All of the available solutions weren't very appealing to me (mixins? ugh!), so I ended up creating a new library to make this process cleaner. It's available here if anyone would like to try it out: https://github.com/monitorjbl/spring-json-view.

The basic usage is pretty simple, you use the `JsonView` object in your controller methods like so:

```
import com.monitorjbl.json.JsonView;
import static com.monitorjbl.json.Match.match;

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/myObject")
@ResponseBody
public void getMyObjects() {
    //get a list of the objects
    List<MyObject> list = myObjectService.list();

    //exclude expensive field
    JsonView.with(list).onClass(MyObject.class, match().exclude("contains"));
}
```

You can also use it outside of Spring:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.module.SimpleModule;
import static com.monitorjbl.json.Match.match;

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();
module.addSerializer(JsonView.class, new JsonViewSerializer());
mapper.registerModule(module);

mapper.writeValueAsString(JsonView.with(list)
      .onClass(MyObject.class, match()
        .exclude("contains"))
      .onClass(MySmallObject.class, match()
        .exclude("id"));
```

Comment: Thank you!  This was the way to go for me. I needed custom JSON views with the same objects in different locations and @JsonIgnore just wouldn't work.  This library made it dead simple get done.

Comment: You made my code cleaner and implementation easier. thank you

Comment: @monitorjbl : this is a bit off track, I have used json views and its solving my purpose. But I am not able to register custom serializer for java.util.Date class(no runtime/compile time error) were as for string I was able to register custom serializer.

Comment: JsonView seems to be part of Jackson object mapper now

Comment: @monitorjbl intresting, i guess i'll try your library

Answer (score 23):

We can do this by setting access to `JsonProperty.Access.WRITE_ONLY` while declaring the property.

```
@JsonProperty( value = "password", access = JsonProperty.Access.WRITE_ONLY)
@SerializedName("password")
private String password;
```

Comment: Just incase someone comes looking, I used this to ignore a property sent in the request, but still have in the response. Other solutions like `@JsonIgnore` ignores the property in both the request and response

Answer (score 22):

Yes, you can specify which fields are serialized as JSON response and which to ignore.
This is what you need to do to implement Dynamically ignore properties.

1) First, you need to add @JsonFilter from com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonFilter on your entity class as.

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonFilter;

@JsonFilter("SomeBeanFilter")
public class SomeBean {

  private String field1;

  private String field2;

  private String field3;

  // getters/setters
}
```

2) Then in your controller, you have to add create the MappingJacksonValue object and set filters on it and in the end, you have to return this object.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonValue;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.FilterProvider;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.SimpleBeanPropertyFilter;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.SimpleFilterProvider;

@RestController
public class FilteringController {

  // Here i want to ignore all properties except field1,field2.
  @GetMapping("/ignoreProperties")
  public MappingJacksonValue retrieveSomeBean() {
    SomeBean someBean = new SomeBean("value1", "value2", "value3");

    SimpleBeanPropertyFilter filter = SimpleBeanPropertyFilter.filterOutAllExcept("field1", "field2");

    FilterProvider filters = new SimpleFilterProvider().addFilter("SomeBeanFilter", filter);

    MappingJacksonValue mapping = new MappingJacksonValue(someBean);

    mapping.setFilters(filters);

    return mapping;
  }
}
```

This is what you will get in response:

```
{
  field1:"value1",
  field2:"value2"
}
```

instead of this:

```
{
  field1:"value1",
  field2:"value2",
  field3:"value3"
}
```

Here you can see it ignores other properties(field3 in this case) in response except for property field1 and field2.

Hope this helps.

Comment: @Shafqat Man, thank you so much, you are my savior. Spent almost a day trying to find out this kind of functionality. This solution is so elegant and simple? and does exactly what was requested. Should be marked as the right answer.

Answer (score 16):

Add `@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)` (forces Jackson to serialize null values) to the class as well as `@JsonIgnore` to the password field.

You could of course set `@JsonIgnore` on createdBy and updatedBy as well if you always want to ignore then and not just in this specific case.

**UPDATE**

In the event that you do not want to add the annotation to the POJO itself, a great option is Jackson's Mixin Annotations. Check out the [documentation](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonMixInAnnotations)

Comment: Can I do it dynamically? Not in POJO? Can I do it in my Controller class?

Comment: Do you mean that you don't want to add the annotations to the POJO?

Comment: Because Sometimes I may want to send all the fields to client side. Sometimes few fields. The fields which I should send to client side is getting from database in the controller class only. After that only I need to set which fields should ignore.

Answer (score 10):

I've solved using only `@JsonIgnore` like @kryger has suggested.
So your getter will become:

```java
@JsonIgnore
public String getEncryptedPwd() {
    return this.encryptedPwd;
}
```

You can set `@JsonIgnore` of course on field, setter or getter like described [here](https://www.concretepage.com/jackson-api/jackson-jsonignore-jsonignoreproperties-and-jsonignoretype#JsonIgnore).

And, if you want to protect encrypted password only on serialization side (e.g. when you need to login your users), add this `@JsonProperty` annotation to your **field**:

```java
@JsonProperty(access = Access.WRITE_ONLY)
private String encryptedPwd;
```

More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12505165/8173143).

Answer (score 6):

If I were you and wanted to do so, I wouldn't use my User entity in Controller layer.Instead I create and use UserDto (Data transfer object) to communicate with business(Service) layer and Controller.
You can use Apache BeanUtils(copyProperties method) to copy data from User entity to UserDto.

Answer (score 5):

I have created a JsonUtil which can be used to ignore fields at runtime while giving a response.

Example Usage :
     First argument should be any POJO class (Student) and ignoreFields is comma seperated fields you want to ignore in response.

```
 Student st = new Student();
 createJsonIgnoreFields(st,"firstname,age");

import java.util.logging.Logger;

import org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectWriter;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.FilterProvider;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.impl.SimpleBeanPropertyFilter;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.impl.SimpleFilterProvider;

public class JsonUtil {

  public static String createJsonIgnoreFields(Object object, String ignoreFields) {
     try {
         ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
         mapper.getSerializationConfig().addMixInAnnotations(Object.class, JsonPropertyFilterMixIn.class);
         String[] ignoreFieldsArray = ignoreFields.split(",");
         FilterProvider filters = new SimpleFilterProvider()
             .addFilter("filter properties by field names",
                 SimpleBeanPropertyFilter.serializeAllExcept(ignoreFieldsArray));
         ObjectWriter writer = mapper.writer().withFilters(filters);
         return writer.writeValueAsString(object);
     } catch (Exception e) {
         //handle exception here
     }
     return "";
   }

   public static String createJson(Object object) {
        try {
         ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
         ObjectWriter writer = mapper.writer().withDefaultPrettyPrinter();
         return writer.writeValueAsString(object);
        }catch (Exception e) {
         //handle exception here
        }
        return "";
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

I've found a solution for me with Spring and jackson

**First specify the filter name in the entity**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "SECTEUR")
@JsonFilter(ModelJsonFilters.SECTEUR_FILTER)
public class Secteur implements Serializable {

/** Serial UID */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 5697181222899184767L;

/**
 * Unique ID
 */
@Id
@JsonView(View.SecteurWithoutChildrens.class)
@Column(name = "id")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private long id;

@JsonView(View.SecteurWithoutChildrens.class)
@Column(name = "code", nullable = false, length = 35)
private String code;

/**
 * Identifiant du secteur parent
 */
@JsonView(View.SecteurWithoutChildrens.class)
@Column(name = "id_parent")
private Long idParent;

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "id_parent")
private List<Secteur> secteursEnfants = new ArrayList<>(0);

}
```

**Then you can see the constants filters names class with the default FilterProvider used in spring configuration**

```
public class ModelJsonFilters {

public final static String SECTEUR_FILTER = "SecteurFilter";
public final static String APPLICATION_FILTER = "ApplicationFilter";
public final static String SERVICE_FILTER = "ServiceFilter";
public final static String UTILISATEUR_FILTER = "UtilisateurFilter";

public static SimpleFilterProvider getDefaultFilters() {
    SimpleBeanPropertyFilter theFilter = SimpleBeanPropertyFilter.serializeAll();
    return new SimpleFilterProvider().setDefaultFilter(theFilter);
}

}
```

**Spring configuration :**

```
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "fr.sodebo")

public class ApiRootConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
private EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;


/**
 * config qui permet d'éviter les "Lazy loading Error" au moment de la
 * conversion json par jackson pour les retours des services REST<br>
 * on permet à jackson d'acceder à sessionFactory pour charger ce dont il a
 * besoin
 */
@Override
public void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {

    super.configureMessageConverters(converters);
    MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter converter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    // config d'hibernate pour la conversion json
    mapper.registerModule(getConfiguredHibernateModule());//

    // inscrit les filtres json
    subscribeFiltersInMapper(mapper);

    // config du comportement de json views
    mapper.configure(MapperFeature.DEFAULT_VIEW_INCLUSION, false);

    converter.setObjectMapper(mapper);
    converters.add(converter);
}

/**
 * config d'hibernate pour la conversion json
 * 
 * @return Hibernate5Module
 */
private Hibernate5Module getConfiguredHibernateModule() {
    SessionFactory sessionFactory = entityManagerFactory.unwrap(SessionFactory.class);
    Hibernate5Module module = new Hibernate5Module(sessionFactory);
    module.configure(Hibernate5Module.Feature.FORCE_LAZY_LOADING, true);

    return module;

}

/**
 * inscrit les filtres json
 * 
 * @param mapper
 */
private void subscribeFiltersInMapper(ObjectMapper mapper) {

    mapper.setFilterProvider(ModelJsonFilters.getDefaultFilters());

}

}
```

**Endly I can specify a specific filter in restConstoller when i need....**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{id}/droits/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public MappingJacksonValue getListDroits(@PathVariable long id) {

    LOGGER.debug("Get all droits of user with id {}", id);

    List<Droit> droits = utilisateurService.findDroitsDeUtilisateur(id);

    MappingJacksonValue value;

    UtilisateurWithSecteurs utilisateurWithSecteurs = droitsUtilisateur.fillLists(droits).get(id);

    value = new MappingJacksonValue(utilisateurWithSecteurs);

    FilterProvider filters = ModelJsonFilters.getDefaultFilters().addFilter(ModelJsonFilters.SECTEUR_FILTER, SimpleBeanPropertyFilter.serializeAllExcept("secteursEnfants")).addFilter(ModelJsonFilters.APPLICATION_FILTER,
            SimpleBeanPropertyFilter.serializeAllExcept("services"));

    value.setFilters(filters);
    return value;

}
```

Comment: why so complications for an easy question

Answer (score 1):

Place `@JsonIgnore` on the field or its getter, or create a custom dto

```
@JsonIgnore
private String encryptedPwd;
```

or as mentioned above by `ceekay` annotate it with `@JsonProperty` where access attribute is set to write only

```
@JsonProperty( value = "password", access = JsonProperty.Access.WRITE_ONLY)
private String encryptedPwd;
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi I have achieved dynamic filtering by using **Gson** library like in the below:

```
JsonObject jsonObj = new Gson().fromJson(mapper.writeValueAsString(sampleObject), JsonObject.class);
jsonObj.remove("someProperty");
String data = new Gson().toJson(jsonObj);
```

Answer (score 1):

> Can I do it dynamically?

Yes, you can use a combination of Jackson's **PropertyFilter** and **mixins**.

### Explanation

Jackson has a `PropertyFilter` interface to implement a filter to ignore fields dynamically. The problem is that filter has to be defined on the DTO/POJO class using the `@JsonFilter` annotation.

To avoid adding a `@JsonFilter` on class we can use `ObjectMapper`'s `addMixIn` method to *"dynamically"* add this annotation (and leave our DTO/POJO classes as is).

### Code example

Here is my implementation of the idea provided above. We can call `toJson()` with two arguments: (1) object to be serialized and (2) lambda (Java's Predicate) to be used in PropertyFilter:

```java
public class JsonService {

    public String toJson(Object object, Predicate<PropertyWriter> filter) {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        FilterProvider filterProvider = new SimpleFilterProvider()
                .addFilter("DynamicFilter", new DynamicFilter(filter));
        mapper.setFilterProvider(filterProvider);
        mapper.addMixIn(object.getClass(), DynamicFilterMixin.class);
        try {
            return mapper.writeValueAsString(object);
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            throw new MyException(e);
        }
    }

    private static final class DynamicFilter extends SimpleBeanPropertyFilter {

        private Predicate<PropertyWriter> filter;

        private DynamicFilter(Predicate<PropertyWriter> filter) {
            this.filter = filter;
        }

        protected boolean include(BeanPropertyWriter writer) {
            return include((PropertyWriter) writer);
        }

        protected boolean include(PropertyWriter writer) {
            return filter.test(writer);
        }
    }

    @JsonFilter("DynamicFilter")
    private interface DynamicFilterMixin {
    }

}
```

Now we can call `toJson` and filter fields during a serialization:

1. Filtering by name

```java
new JsonService().toJson(object, w -> !w.getName().equals("fieldNameToBeIgnored"));
```

2. Filtering by annotation (on the field)

```java
new JsonService().toJson(object, w -> w.getAnnotation(MyAnnotation.class) == null);
```

### Unit tests

Here are the unit tests for the class above:

```java
public class JsonServiceTest {
    
    private JsonService jsonService = new JsonService();
    
    @Test
    public void withoutFiltering() {
        MyObject object = getObject();
        String json = jsonService.toJson(object, w -> true);
        assertEquals("{\"myString\":\"stringValue\",\"myInteger\":10,\"myBoolean\":true}", json);
    }

    @Test
    public void filteredByFieldName() {
        MyObject object = getObject();
        String json = jsonService.toJson(object, w -> !w.getName().equals("myString"));
        assertEquals("{\"myInteger\":10,\"myBoolean\":true}", json);
    }

    @Test
    public void filteredByAnnotation() {
        MyObject object = getObject();
        String json = jsonService.toJson(object, w -> w.getAnnotation(Deprecated.class) == null);
        assertEquals("{\"myString\":\"stringValue\",\"myInteger\":10}", json);
    }
    
    private MyObject getObject() {
        MyObject object = new MyObject();
        object.myString = "stringValue";
        object.myInteger = 10;
        object.myBoolean = true;
        return object;
    }
    
    private static class MyObject {
        private String myString;
        private int myInteger;
        @Deprecated
        private boolean myBoolean;

        public String getMyString() {
            return myString;
        }

        public void setMyString(String myString) {
            this.myString = myString;
        }

        public int getMyInteger() {
            return myInteger;
        }

        public void setMyInteger(int myInteger) {
            this.myInteger = myInteger;
        }

        public boolean isMyBoolean() {
            return myBoolean;
        }

        public void setMyBoolean(boolean myBoolean) {
            this.myBoolean = myBoolean;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Would not creating a `UserJsonResponse` class and populating with the wanted fields be a cleaner solution?

Returning directly a JSON seems a great solution when you want to give all the model back. Otherwise it just gets messy.

In the future, for example you might want to have a JSON field that does not match any Model field and then you're in a bigger trouble.

Answer (score 0):

This is a clean utility tool for the above [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51990626/1970299) :

```
@GetMapping(value = "/my-url")
public @ResponseBody
MappingJacksonValue getMyBean() {
    List<MyBean> myBeans = Service.findAll();
    MappingJacksonValue mappingValue = MappingFilterUtils.applyFilter(myBeans, MappingFilterUtils.JsonFilterMode.EXCLUDE_FIELD_MODE, "MyFilterName", "myBiggerObject.mySmallerObject.mySmallestObject");
    return mappingValue;
}

//AND THE UTILITY CLASS
public class MappingFilterUtils {

    public enum JsonFilterMode {
        INCLUDE_FIELD_MODE, EXCLUDE_FIELD_MODE
    }
    public static MappingJacksonValue applyFilter(Object object, final JsonFilterMode mode, final String filterName, final String... fields) {
        if (fields == null || fields.length == 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("You should pass at least one field");
        }
        return applyFilter(object, mode, filterName, new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(fields)));
    }

    public static MappingJacksonValue applyFilter(Object object, final JsonFilterMode mode, final String filterName, final Set<String> fields) {
        if (fields == null || fields.isEmpty()) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("You should pass at least one field");
        }

        SimpleBeanPropertyFilter filter = null;
        switch (mode) {
            case EXCLUDE_FIELD_MODE:
                filter = SimpleBeanPropertyFilter.serializeAllExcept(fields);
                break;
            case INCLUDE_FIELD_MODE:
                filter = SimpleBeanPropertyFilter.filterOutAllExcept(fields);
                break;
        }

        FilterProvider filters = new SimpleFilterProvider().addFilter(filterName, filter);
        MappingJacksonValue mapping = new MappingJacksonValue(object);
        mapping.setFilters(filters);
        return mapping;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To acheive dynamic filtering follow the link - https://iamvickyav.medium.com/spring-boot-dynamically-ignore-fields-while-converting-java-object-to-json-e8d642088f55

1. Add the @JsonFilter("Filter name") annotation to the model class.
2. Inside the controller function add the code:-

   ```
   SimpleBeanPropertyFilter simpleBeanPropertyFilter =
           SimpleBeanPropertyFilter.serializeAllExcept("id", "dob"); 

   FilterProvider filterProvider = new SimpleFilterProvider()
           .addFilter("Filter name", simpleBeanPropertyFilter);

   List<User> userList = userService.getAllUsers();
   MappingJacksonValue mappingJacksonValue = new MappingJacksonValue(userList);
   mappingJacksonValue.setFilters(filterProvider);

   return mappingJacksonValue;
   ```
3. make sure the return type is MappingJacksonValue.

Answer (score 0):

Simply create new dto class without field password.

```
class UserDto {
      // ... your field without password field
}
```

convert your User.java into UserDto.java on response.

Answer (score -6):

In your entity class add `@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)` annotation to resolve the problem

it will look like

```
@Entity
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
```

Comment: Totally irrelevantly answered. The purpose of the question is different while the answer is about something else. -1 for that