# Ignore Java Object's Selected fields while Sending it as JSON

Tags: java, json, spring-mvc

I am new to Spring-MVC.

I am sending data to my view as JSON, and there I am deserializing it to a string, but I want to pass only selected fields, I don't want all fields to send there but how to ignore selected fields I don't know.

My class POJO code :

```
public class account{

    private Integer userId;
    private String userName;
    private String emailId;

    //getter - setter

}
```

In some activity I don't want some fields so I want to avoid that fields so any idea on this confusing situation ?

Comment: You're looking for the ```@JsonIgnore``` annotation. Google search will help you tremendously on your long and perilous journey through the valley of Spring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the annotation `@JsonIgnoreProperties("fieldname")` to your `POJO`.
or you can use `@JsonIgnore` also before field name that you want to ignore while deserializing JSON.

example :

```
@JsonIgnore
@JsonProperty(value = "user_password")
public java.lang.String getUserPassword()
{
    return userPassword;
}
```

[Here Is my Answer for Similar Question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23101260/ignore-fields-from-java-object-dynamically-while-sending-as-json-from-spring-mvc/23101380#23101380)

Comment: @user3713749 : pleasure to hear that solved your problem. Keep smiling