# Spring - REST Controller Return to return some specific fields in JSON

Tags: json, spring, rest, collections, controller

I wanted to expose (though Controller) some specific fields of my Entity (let say *Person*), which has let say:

- id
- name
- number
- ...

And I wanted to prepare my REST controller, so it will return array of objects - but only id and name of objects:

```
[
  {
    "name": "name1",
    "id": 1
  },
  {
    "name": "name2",
    "id": 2
  }
  ...
]
```

I found something similar - [Spring Rest Controller Return Specific Fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30558784/spring-rest-controller-return-specific-fields) however the code behind it, is not looking well:

```
public @ResponseBody List<Map<String, Object>> getAll() {
    List<Person> allPersons = personService.findAll();

    List<Map<String, Object>> resultCollection = new ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>();
    for (Person person : allPersons) {
        Map<String, Object> personValuesMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        personValuesMap.put("id", person.getId());
        personValuesMap.put("name", person.getName());
        resultCollection.add(personValuesMap);
    }
    return resultCollection;
}
```

Is there any more beauty/clear/spring way to achieve this?

Comment: Use Json View https://spring.io/blog/2014/12/02/latest-jackson-integration-improvements-in-spring