# How to omit a field in JSON returned value in Spring

Tags: json, spring, mongodb, spring-mvc, jackson

I have a MongoDB which stores user information including the user's password. Users can call a GET request to retrieve all the user's information from the database. But I do not want the client to see the password, just every thing else.

Here, the client can get a user's personal info provided he has his username:

```
/* Get user by username */
    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET, value="/getByUsername")
    public @ResponseBody User getUserByUsername(@RequestParam("username") String username) {
        return repo.findByUsername(username);
    }
```

the returned statement is in a JSON format like this:

{
    id: "559e8d522de3b3e03b06457c"
    firstname: "bob"
    lastname: "alice"
    username: "username"
    password: "testpassword"
    address: "2020 america road"
    city: "The City"
    state: "maryland"
    zipCode: "99999"
    phoneNumber: "3421345"
    email: "pasdf@test.com"
}

This is what is being sent to the client and what the client sees. But I want to omit the password field from this JSON document.

How do I do that?

Comment: You can have a look this in [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23101260/ignore-fields-from-java-object-dynamically-while-sending-as-json-from-spring-mvc)

Answer (score 1):

Mark the getter for password with [`@JsonIgnore`](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.0.2/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonIgnore.html).