# Adding table joins to existing project causes infinite recursion

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate

I work on this project:
https://github.com/s1ddok/todosapp

Here you can find all sources for entity etc. What I'm trying to do is to add a connection between `TODO` and `USER`. I want that to be a many-to-one relation since one user can have multiple todos, but todos can only have one owner.

I've created a join table in my MySQL database, with foreign keys etc.

Then I added following annotations:
[image]

[image]

And that is raising fatal error on Application start:

```
Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: Could not write JSON: Infinite recursion (StackOverflowError) (through reference chain: sample.todosapp.spring.domain.User["todos"]->org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentSet[0]->sample.todosapp.spring.domain.Todo["user"]->sample.todosapp.spring.domain.User["todos"]->org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentSet[0]->sample.todosapp.spring.domain.Todo["user"]->sample.todosapp.spring.domain.User["todos"]->org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentSet[0]->sample.todosapp.spring.domain.Todo["user"]->sample.todosapp.spring.domain.User["todos"]->org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentSet[0]->sample.todosapp.spring.domain.Todo["user"]->sample.todosapp.spring.domain.User["todos"]
```

......

I'm completely lost. I search all related questions and tried all possible annotation variants, but still have no luch. What exactly I did wrong?

Comment: I've changed fetch type to .LAZY and now it compiles and runs but problem still exists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use mappedBy in one of your attributes and not define the relationship in both of them. Remove the annotation @JoinColumn from the HashSet Todo and change `@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)` to `@OneToMany(mappedBy = "user" , cascade = CascadeType.ALL)`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I tried a different approach. If you need both relationship (`@OneToMany` and `@ManyToOne`)in your code (like my case), what should you do?

So you should use `@JsonIgnore` annotation to break the loop. And the problem was solved. Like it is suggested in [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23101260/ignore-fields-from-java-object-dynamically-while-sending-as-json-from-spring-mvc)

My answer is late, but hope to help someone else!