# How to return only some fields in the response

Tags: java, web-services, jersey

I have made a service that returns an array of UserSettings objects:

```
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Path("/")
public Response getBulkSettings(@QueryParam("fields") List<String> fields, @QueryParam("ids") List<String> ids) {
 List<UserSettings> responseArr = mailerService.fetchSettings(ids,fields);
return Response.ok(responseArr).build();
}
```

When I make a GET request on the URL 
http://localhost:8181/settings?ids=123&fields=customData,user_id
I get the following:

```
[
{
    "id": 0,
    "user_id": 123,
    "customData": "testCustomDataFor123",
    "deactivationDate": null
}
]
```

While what I want is :

```
[
{
    "user_id": 123,
    "customData": "testCustomDataFor123"
}
]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23101260/ignore-fields-from-java-object-dynamically-while-sending-as-json-from-spring-mvc).

Answer (score 3):

Put `@JsonIgnore` at the fields you don't want or its getter.

Answer (score 1):

Using the annotation `@JsonIgnore` is a solution if you can decide on the attributes to be filtered at compile-time. In your example you want to filter at run-time, which can be achieved using techniques from your JSON library. For example, when using Genson you could do something like this:

```
new GensonBuilder().exclude("password").create();
```

However, by doing so you loose the advantage of not having to care about how your response is serialised into JSON. Therefore, I would like to suggest that you think if it is really necessary that clients can dynamically decide on the attributes to be returned. Another solution might be to use media-types other than `application/json` that would allow the client to request different views of the resource. Jersey distributes incoming requests using the media-type given in the `Accept` header to the methods in the service class. In each method you can then work with different sub-classes of your `UserSettings` class that exclude different attributes using the annotation `@JsonIgnore`.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it how the other responses suggests.
Another option with JAX-RS would be to leverage another Genson feature that enables you to filter what properties should be included or excluded.
To do so register a custom Genson instance with this special Filter.

```
UrlQueryParamFilter filter = new UrlQueryParamFilter();
Genson genson = new GensonBuilder().useRuntimePropertyFilter(filter).create();
new ResourceConfig()
  .register(new GensonJaxRSFeature().use(genson))
  .register(filter);
```

And then in the query define the properties you want to include or exclude like that: `http://localhost/foo/bar?filter=age&filter=name`.

Some more explanation can be found [here](http://owlike.github.io/genson/Documentation/Extensions/#jax-rs-jersey--cie).