# Json Entity Serialization in case one-to-many; selective child's fields serialization

Tags: json, serialization, gson

I have web project with jpa(2.1) and hibernate(5.3.6). I have to do some servlets which have to save and retrieve me some data.
So, if I have two classes:

```
public class Parent{

@Column(name="id")
private int id;

@Column(name="name")
private String name;

...

@OneToMany(orphanRemoval = true, mappedBy = "parent")
@Cascade({ CascadeType.ALL })
private List<Child> childs = new ArrayList<Child>();
}
```

and

```
public class Child{

@Column(name="id")
private int id;

@Column(name="name")
private String name;

...

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@Cascade({ CascadeType.ALL })
@JoinColumn(name = "parentId", foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "MyForeignKey"), nullable = true, updatable = true, insertable = true)
private Parent parent;

}
```

I have two cases:

1. I need to get the parent with all childs but when serializing i want to see just child's id, like:

   [{
   "id":1,
   "name": "parent1",
   "childs":[{
     "id":10
     },
     {
     "id":18
     }]
   }]
2. I need to get no matter which child and to see all properties, like:

   [{
       "id":10,
       "name": "child10"
       }]

I tried with **gson** library annotation on different fields

```
@Expose(serialize="false", deserialize="true")
```

but I can't achieve both of behaviors ( first case and second case), i get or:

parent ->

```
[{
"id":1,
"name": "parent1"
}]
```

with separate child ->

```
[{
"id":10,
"name": "child10"
}]
```

or

parent ->

```
[{
"id":1,
"name": "parent1",
"childs":[{
   "id":10
   },
   {
   "id":18
   }]
}]
```

with separate child ->

```
[{
"id":10
}]
```

So, can you help me please with this problem? It's possible to achieve both case 1 and 2 in separate requests like I want?

Thank you.

Comment: Tagging your question as JSON rather than JPA would mean it accurately reflects what you want. JPA != JSON, JPA doesn't do serialisation

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ignore fields from Java object dynamically while sending as JSON from Spring MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23101260/ignore-fields-from-java-object-dynamically-while-sending-as-json-from-spring-mvc)