# I want to remove few fields from JSON result field T result. I am not able to to delete specific fields from T result

Tags: java, spring-mvc

As per code given i want to remove few fields from  in ResultJSON.
In  field I am going pass list of ResultBean.

I am setting fields in result field like resultJson.setResult(ResultBeanList)

Note: ResultBean is not a JSON object. It simple Java bean.
Hope You understand my issue.

```
public class ResultJson<T> {
    private Integer success;
    private T result;
    private String message;
    private String errorCode;   
}

public class ResultBean implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private String customerName;
    private String customerCode;
    private String customerAlias;
    private String pOR;
    private String pOD;
}
```

We can skip/remove fields in JSON but question how can we delete fields from inside of JSON fields.

Comment: are those "fields" you want to delete from JSON are NULL or NON NULL?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ignore fields from Java object dynamically while sending as JSON from Spring MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23101260/ignore-fields-from-java-object-dynamically-while-sending-as-json-from-spring-mvc)

Comment: @ScanQR they would be null and that's why want to hide/remove from json result but thing is that it(ResultBean) is not JSON object just setting(resultJson.setResult(ResultBeanList)) it to JSON object(ResultJson).