# Return only specific fields of model from api in spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I am writing a spring boot api which fetches some data from db, store in model object & returns it. But I want to return only few fields of the model as api response.

```
List<MyModel> myModelList = new ArrayList<>();
mongoUserCollection.find().into(myModelList);



 class MyModel{
    public int id; 
    public String name;
    public String lastname;
    public int age;
// getter & setter of all properties
    }
```

I am showing myModelList as response. In response its showing all the fields. How to show only specific fields like id and age only. Selecting only id & age from db will still show all fields of model in response (name & lastname will be shown as null).
Is there any way apart from creating new ModelView class or setting JsonIgnore as this model?

Comment: Does this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23101260/ignore-fields-from-java-object-dynamically-while-sending-as-json-from-spring-mvc) helps? `@JsonIgnore`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If the model which you are returning is going to be specific to single API go with `@JsonIgnore`, the below example will ignore the `id` in the response

```java
class MyModel{
    @JsonIgnore
    public int id; 
    public String name;
    public String lastname;
    public int age;
}
```

But let say the same model is going to be used for different API and each API has different type of result then I would highly recommend `@JsonView` to handle those. A simple example will be below (will consider `MyModel` from your question)

Create a class **Views.java** with an empty interface

```java
public class Views {
    public interface MyResponseViews {};
}
```

**In Model**

```java
class MyModel{
  public int id; 
  @JsonView(Views.MyResponseViews.class)
  public String name;
  @JsonView(Views.MyResponseViews.class)
  public String lastname;
  public int age;
}
```

Last thing you have to add to the controller that send this response (Assuming your controller here)

**MyModelController.java**

```java
class MyModelController {
   // Autowiring MyModelService ...

   
   @GetMapping("/get")
   @JsonView(Views.MyResponseViews.class)
   public ResponseEntity get() {
     // Your logic to return the result
   }

}
```

The above will return only `name` and `lastname`
Refer this for more detail [this](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-json-view-annotation)

Comment: Marked this as accepted. JsonView is what exactly I was looking for.. thanks