# SpringMVC: How to filter a JSON-Response dynamically and selectively?

Tags: java, json, spring, jpa

I need to exclude fields before a JSON response is sent, depending on the logged in user. Concretely I have [user]s belonging to [company]s.

If the logged-in-user is an administor, he/she should be able to see all companies with all users. If the user is not an administrator he/she should be able to see all companies and the list of users of his/her company, but not the userlist of foreign companies.
Therefore i have to filter the result list not only dynamically but also selectively.

I have already found this thread: [How do I exclude fields with Jackson not using annotations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13764280/how-do-i-exclude-fields-with-jackson-not-using-annotations)
and this thread:  [Jackson Change JsonIgnore Dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8179986/jackson-change-jsonignore-dynamically)

Is there a way to iterate through the result set to remove certain fields?

Comment: Use the solution provided in "how do I exclude fields with Jackson not using annotations" and change the input (the field name list) based on the user.

Comment: But that wouldn't be working because it has to be selective (if I got this right). I don't want to remove fields from every item in the list but only from certain items.