# Exclude some field from object while return

Tags: java, spring, return

I have object that have attributes `id, name, description`.

In some case i want to return whole object but in some i want to return only `id`, suppose when I insert new record it should only return id that is newly generated.

```
public class DTO {
    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    private String description;
    // getter-setter
}
```

controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{cname}/met", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public DTO addMet(@PathVariable String  cname, @RequestBody DTO met) {
    return service.addMet(met); // service return whole DTO object that is newly added with new Id
}
```

I want to return only `id` as response, so any help or guidance on it that how to do so ?

Thank you.

Comment: I didn't understand it. The method `addMet` cannot return `Integer` instead of `DTO`?

Comment: @MarceloKeiti : I want to return response as `Json` like `{id:'1'}`, if i ll return it as integer it will just give me `id` in response.

Comment: Ok, so return a String and format the DTO instance using some framework like Gson.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm missing something, you could change the return type of the method and return the `id` with something like

```
public Integer addMet(@PathVariable String  cname, @RequestBody DTO met) {
    return service.addMet(met).getId();
}
```

It might be a good idea to log the full return (assuming you have overridden `toString()`)

```
public Integer addMet(@PathVariable String  cname, @RequestBody DTO met) {
    LOG.debug("Adding: %s", met);
    DTO r = service.addMet(met);
    LOG.debug("Result: %s", r);
    return r.getId();
}
```

As for your custom class, you could write an inner class like

```
static class Identity {
    public Identity(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    private final int id;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return String.format("id: %d", id);
    }
}
```

and return that

```
public Identity addMet(@PathVariable String  cname, @RequestBody DTO met) {
    LOG.debug("Adding: %s", met);
    DTO r = service.addMet(met);
    LOG.debug("Result: %s", r);
    return new Identity(r.getId());
}
```

Comment: I want to return response as `Json` like `{id:'1'}`, if i ll return it as integer it will just give me `id` in response.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the JsonIgnore annotation. http://jackson.codehaus.org/1.0.1/javadoc/org/codehaus/jackson/annotate/JsonIgnore.html

Comment: Yes I know this already. But in some situation I want to return whole object and in some I want to just return Id. So it should be kind of dynamic.

Comment: maybe this will help then, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8179986/jackson-change-jsonignore-dynamically  The blog pointed out even has a nice example, I had used it some time back when I was learning.

Answer (score 0):

In your controller, set the fields you want to exclude to `null`.

Also configure Spring's underlying Jackson `ObjectMapper` instance to not serialize `null` fields:

```
@Configuration
public class ServiceContext
    extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport {

    @Override
    public void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
        MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter converter = this.getConverter();
        converters.add(converter);
    }

    @Bean
    public MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter getConverter() {
        MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter converter = 
            new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
        ObjectMapper mapper = this.getObjectMapper();
        converter.setObjectMapper(mapper);
        return converter;
    }

    @Bean
    public ObjectMapper getObjectMapper() {
        JsonFactory factory = new JsonFactory();
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(factory);
        mapper.setSerializationInclusion(Include.NON_NULL); // don't serialize nulls
        mapper.disable(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES);
        return factory;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the @JsonView

> JSON Views
>
> It can sometimes be useful to filter contextually objects serialized
>   to the HTTP response body. In order to provide such capabilities,
>   Spring MVC now has builtin support for Jackson’s Serialization Views.

[Here is a well explained example](https://spring.io/blog/2014/12/02/latest-jackson-integration-improvements-in-spring)