# Returning different Resource type Lists from one method

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-hateoas

I have this method for a GET request with a parameter embedded. The main idea is if the link contains ?embedded=true it returns the entity and if it's not true then it returns a DTO object:

```
@GetMapping("/todos") 
    public List<Resource<?>> getAllToDoNote(@RequestParam(value = "embedded",required =false)String embedded){
        List<Resource<ToDoNote>> noteResources = new ArrayList<Resource<ToDoNote>>();
        List<ToDoNote> allNotes = toDoNoteService.getAllToDoNote();

        if(embedded!=null && embedded.equals("true")) {
            for(int i=0; i< allNotes.size();i++) {
            Resource<ToDoNote> noteResource = new Resource<>(allNotes.get(i));
            //Link linkTo = linkTo(methodOn(this.getClass()).getNotesUsers(allNotes.get(i).getId())).withRel("users");

            //noteResource.add(linkTo);
            noteResources.add(noteResource);
            }

            //return toDoNoteService.getAllToDoNote();
            return noteResources;
        }

        else {
            //System.out.println("embedded " +embedded);
            List<Resource<ToDoNoteDTO>> dtoResources = new ArrayList<Resource<ToDoNoteDTO>>();
            notes = toDoNoteService.getAllToDoNote();
            List<ToDoNoteDTO> noteDtos = new ArrayList<ToDoNoteDTO>();
            for(int i=0; i<notes.size(); i++) {
                //System.out.println("size" +notes.get(i).getName());
                noteDtos.add(convertToDto(notes.get(i)));
            }

            for(int i=0; i< noteDtos.size();i++) {
                Resource<ToDoNoteDTO> dtoResource = new Resource<>(noteDtos.get(i));
                Link linkTo = linkTo(methodOn(this.getClass()).getNotesUsers(allNotes.get(i).getId())).withRel("users");

                dtoResource.add(linkTo);
                dtoResources.add(dtoResource);
                }

            return dtoResources;
            //return null;
        }

    }


@Validated

public class ToDoNote {
    private Integer id;
    @NotNull(message = "Name may not be null")
    private String name;
    @JsonFormat(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd")
    private Date dateToComplete;
    private String description;
    private Integer priority;
    private Boolean completed;
    private ArrayList<User> users; 
....

}

public class ToDoNoteDTO {
    private Integer id;
    @NotNull(message = "Name may not be null")
    private String name;
    @JsonFormat(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd")
    private Date dateToComplete;
    private String description;
    private Integer priority;
    private Boolean completed;
....
}
```

However, I'm getting errors on the return lines:
Type missmatch: cannot convert from List< Resource < ToDoNote >> to List < Resource < ? >>. If I place question marks everywhere it lets me to run the program however then it returns the links with other fields which are null. 
Are the are any other methods on how to return two different types? Since I need either to return a full entity or a DTO which does not contain all the fields.

**EDIT**

I have been able to get it working using Resources> instead of List, however now there is the _embedded property and after searching a bit there does not seem a way to remove it. So I would just want to get some ideas on how to handle this case where to respond with different entities based on the given embedded parameter. Thank you.

**EDIT2**
Added the entity and DTO class.

Comment: Since there is a DTO, why would the Entity be exposed to a client?

Comment: Well for my program if they wish to see the whole entity they can with the ?embedded parameter. That is the desired functionality.

Comment: Why not just always provide the whole object?  Or if that would make the object too large, make it more RESTful by providing [links within the response](https://restfulapi.net/hateoas/).

Comment: I'm sure there are better ways, but this is what I need to do. Also, when I'm providing the DTO I provide the links, and if it is embedded=true then I provide the objects themselves instead of the links.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8179986/jackson-change-jsonignore-dynamically) might help.

Comment: Just to clarify your intention: By default you return a list with resource objects of type TodoNote, those have some own properties and links to other resources. If the query parameter `embedded` is set to `true` the same endpoint should return the a list of an altered resource type, which has the same properties as TodoNote but instead to link to other resources, these should be embedded. Is this correct? If yes, please make sure to clarify this in your question.

Comment: By default it returns a ToDoNoteDTO which does not have one object inside and instead a link to it is added. If embedded=true then instead of the link the ToDoNote itself is returned with the object (that the DTO does not have).

Comment: As you see, providing those objects may clarify the question. Phrases like "does not have one object inside" are a bit misleading.

Comment: Alright, I will edit my question with the 2 classes.

Comment: @SvajunasKavaliauskas More info why your links are not rendering correctly: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-hateoas/issues/709#issuecomment-386629637 It seems like you are not interested in using HAL, are you sure Spring HATEOAS is for you?

Comment: @sn42 Thank you. I'm now returning Resources instead of a List and it seems to be working alright. And by I'm not interested in HAL did you mean I'm not going with the standard of how it is supposed to be?

Comment: @SvajunasKavaliauskas In 0.25.x Spring HATEOAS either uses the default rendering or HAL, HAL is used if u use the spring boot starter (but you can disable it). You can either customize those default rendering (create your own mixins, jackson module etc. see [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-hateoas/tree/0.25.1.RELEASE/src/main/java/org/springframework/hateoas/hal)) or stick to HAL. Version 1.x adds some alternatives to hal if i remember correctly.

Comment: @SvajunasKavaliauskas "did you mean I'm not going with the standard of how it is supposed to be?" Not necessarily, as mentioned before you have alternatives to HAL.But if you dont use hal you have to specify how you want to render Links, Resource, Resources on your own.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return different fields depending on the user's needs I'd advice using spring data rest projections: see https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#projections-excerpts